# Efficiency of stream.map.filter

Tags: java, java-stream

Consider this class -

```
Class Person {
    private Integer age;
    private Integer getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

`List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>` .. of some 20 instances

Now I have to find all the adults persons(age >= 18)
I have two way to do it with stream -

1. ```
   list.stream()
       .map(person -> person.getAge())
       .filter(age -> age >= 18)
       .count()
   ```
2. ```
   list.stream()
       .filter(person -> person.getAge() >= 18)
       .count()
   ```

Now my question is: will approach 1, adds extra iteration to perform the task or will it be just one iteration like approach 2?

Comment: It will still be a single iteration.

Comment: The question to ask yourself and to justify the use of the API would be, *"Do you really need to `map` the `Person` object to its `age` just to count the people with age above 18?"*

Answer (score 3):

A stream can only be consumed once, so there's no "extra iterations". There's an additional step, so technically the second one is more efficient. However you'd have to have millions of elements, and even then it would be pretty much unnoticeable.

In this case it's mainly a choice in which style you prefer. Since they're both easily readable, the second one makes more sense as it is simpler.

Comment: The second is probably a little bit more efficient than the second, because it performs a step less.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel sure, of course in this case with only 20 instances it won't make a difference. I would use the second form, because there's no significant added clarity in the first version.

Answer (score 1):

Stream.filter and Stream.map are intermediate operations that return a new stream. **But** the intermediate operations are always ***lazy*** : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps

> Processing streams lazily allows for significant efficiencies; in a pipeline such as the filter-map-sum example above, filtering, mapping, and summing can be fused into a single pass on the data, with minimal intermediate state.

Answer (score 0):

**Using Java Stream Operations might sometime be a little tricky.**

I will show you an example which is written in Kotlin and show the Decompiled Version

Imagine class person with a **name** value

By these codes I want to filter **names** by the value of **age**

**Function A : using Filter and Map**

```
fun a(list: List<Person>): List<String> {
    return list
        .filter { it.age >= 18 }
        .map { it.name }
}
```

**Function B: using a simple Foreach**

```
fun b(list: List<Person>): List<String> {
    val result = mutableListOf<String>()
    for (item in list) {
        if (item.age >= 18) {
            result.add(item.name)
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

How beautiful Function A is!!

**Now Lets take a look what happens under the hood:**

### In Fact, Function A uses Two While Iterators to do the same operations

I know it is a little Messy

**Function A : using Filter and Map**

```
public final List a(@NotNull List list) {
  Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(list, "list");
  Iterable $this$map$iv = (Iterable)list;
  int $i$f$map = false;
  Collection destination$iv$iv = (Collection)(new ArrayList());
  int $i$f$mapTo = false;
  Iterator var7 = $this$map$iv.iterator();

  Object item$iv$iv;
  Person it;
  boolean var10;
  while(var7.hasNext()) {
     item$iv$iv = var7.next();
     it = (Person)item$iv$iv;
     var10 = false;
     if (it.getAge() >= 18) {
        destination$iv$iv.add(item$iv$iv);
     }
  }

  $this$map$iv = (Iterable)((List)destination$iv$iv);
  $i$f$map = false;
  destination$iv$iv = (Collection)(new ArrayList(CollectionsKt.collectionSizeOrDefault($this$map$iv, 10)));
  $i$f$mapTo = false;
  var7 = $this$map$iv.iterator();

  while(var7.hasNext()) {
     item$iv$iv = var7.next();
     it = (Person)item$iv$iv;
     var10 = false;
     String var12 = it.getName();
     destination$iv$iv.add(var12);
  }

  return (List)destination$iv$iv;
```

}

**Function B: using a simple Foreach**

```
public final List b(@NotNull List list) {
  Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(list, "list");
  List result = (List)(new ArrayList());
  Iterator var4 = list.iterator();

  while(var4.hasNext()) {
     Person item = (Person)var4.next();
     if (item.getAge() >= 18) {
        String var10001 = item.getName();
        Intrinsics.checkNotNullExpressionValue(var10001, "item.name");
        result.add(var10001);
     }
  }

  return result;
```

}

Answer (score -2):

Actually the second one way is preferable because each `stream` method raises a new stream. For instance a `map` method returns a **new** stream, [here is a doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)
so the second way will be "cheaper" at the point of view of number of calculations for your purpose

btw it's look like you've done a missprint in the second example: not `list.filter` but `list.stream().filter`

Comment: It wont create 2 new streams. please see the doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps (paragraph Processing streams lazily allows for significant efficiencies;).
You can see it in my comment